# Vercel failed to deploy due to node

Tags: node.js, vercel

I can't seem to get vercel to succesfully to build due to this issue.
`node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node) node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)`

I've tried to change the node version down to 18.0.0 and some other versions and still get this error. I have my vercel set to node 18.x.x not sure what else to really do at this point.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: The OS I use is Windows 10, but Vercel is an website I think they use AWS to host sites like netlify. I'm not sure what OS they use but they have a section where you can select which node version you're using and its set to 18.x.x

Answer (score 1):

I found this question posted in Vercel's Github.  I was having the same issue and this fixed it.

https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2867

Removing node from my dependencies was my fix.  I'm guessing this just allows the build to use the version of node that you have set on the server.